# Calculating an average of two ints and converting to a double in java

Tags: java, int, double

I am learning how to use Java and for my coursework I have been asked to construct an application that will read in the exam mark and coursework mark and then print out to 1 decimal place the average of the coursework and exam mark. When I submit it to the coursework submission system it says it's incorrect.

The answer that it's asking for is the answer that my code produces (ex = 71 cw = 40 mark = 55.5)
But for some reason it says this when I submit it:

```
-#### << Differences between expected (<) your answer (>) >> ------------
1c1
< ex= 91 cw = 80 mark = 85.5
---
> ex = 71 cw = 40 mark = 55.5
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

[S] Sorry exercise ci101/1.2 was not correct.
Check the above output for why this attempt failed
```

And when I change the ex to 91 and cw to 80 it asks for > ex = 71 cw = 40 mark = 55.5 again.

```
class Main
{ 
  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    int ExamMark=71;                
    int CourseworkMark=40;

    double cost = (double)(ExamMark + CourseworkMark) / 2; 

    System.out.printf("ex = " + ExamMark + " cw = " + CourseworkMark + " mark = " + cost); 
    System.out.println();

  }

}
```

Comment: Check your spacing in your output make sure it exactly matches

Answer (score 1):

you can make the 2-> 2.0 that will make the result a double.

```
double cost = (ExamMark + CourseworkMark) / 2.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to produce both answers? first 91:80:85.5 then 71:40:55.5 ?

Also, I notice that you are not exactly matching the white space (spacebar) of the expected answer.  It may or may not matter.

Comment: The only answer I need to produce is 71:40:55.5. I have no idea why when I submit my work it asks for that answer :(

Answer (score 0):

The description of the assignment says "read in the exam mark and coursework mark" but you are building in the marks as constants in the program, not reading them.

The coursework submission system is probably running your program with two different inputs to make sure you are really reading them. If you build in either of the inputs, it will report a mismatch for the run with the other input. That is why the reported error changes to always be for the input you did not build in.

You need to modify your program to use marks it reads, probably from System.in. Look carefully at the assignment to see what it says about the input source and format.